# js callbacks to generator based code

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mocha.js, generator

I want test my  server.
Test provide simple scenario:

1. Send request to server
2. Wait for response
3. Check something

I try use [mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) for tests and [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) for requesting.

Example of test:

```
function request(url, query, cb) {
    var req = supertest(app.listen())
        .get(url)
        .query(query)
        .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) {throw (err);}
            cb(res);
        });
}

it('Check something after response', function *(done) {
    request(this.url, this.query, function(res) {/* some after response check here */});
});
```

Now i need reorganize my callback-style code into generators-style code.

I need something like that:

```
it('Check something in response', function *(done) {
    var res = yield request(this.url, this.query);
    /* some after response check here */
});
```

Unfortunately i can't understand what changes i need to do in `request()`

P.S. I don't watch for other `supertest` like solution with appropriate style. I just want to understand how to wrap callback with this simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to rewrite a callbacks code to the generator style, you need:

- a generator function that uses `yield someAsyncFunc(cb)`
- an iterator, created by calling this generator
- the callback function should advance the iterator and set its return value `iter.next(value)`
- finally, to start the whole thing going, you should invoke `next` once on the iterator

Example:

```js
console.info=function(x){document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(x,0,3)+'</pre>')}
//--


// some async function with a callback
function asyncFunc(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        done(Math.random())
    }, 500);
}

// generator
function *gen() {
    var val;
    val = yield asyncFunc(advanceIter);
    console.info(val)
    val = yield asyncFunc(advanceIter);
    console.info(val)
}

// create an iterator
iter = gen()

// define a callback for the async function
function advanceIter(value) {
    iter.next(value);
}

// get the whole machinery started
iter.next()
```

Of course, in the real world, you'd wrap your generator in a function that takes care of all housekeeping. You generator will receive the `advance` argument, which it should blindly pass further as a callback to async functions it uses.

```js
console.info=function(x){document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(x,0,3)+'</pre>')}
//--

function asyncFunc(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        done(Math.random())
    }, 500);
}

function run(gen) {
    var iter = gen(function(value) {
        iter.next(value)
    });
    iter.next()
}

run(function *(advance) {
    var val;
    val = yield asyncFunc(advance);
    console.info(val)
    val = yield asyncFunc(advance);
    console.info(val)
});
```

Note that there are no changes necessary in the async function itself (`request` in your case).

An example with a testing framework:

```
// some async function we're going to test

function asyncFunc(param, cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb(param + '-ok');
    }, 500);
}

// classic async test

describe('async demo', function () {
    it('works', function (done) {
        asyncFunc('foobar', function (result) {
            expect(result).toBe('foobar-ok');
            done();
        })
    });
});

// generator test
// note that asyncFunc itself remains unchanged

function run(gen) {
    var iter = gen(function (value) {
        iter.next(value)
    });
    iter.next()
}

describe('yield demo', function () {
    it('works', function (done) {
        run(function *(advance) {
            var result = yield asyncFunc('barbaz', advance);
            expect(result).toBe('barbaz-ok');
            done();
        })
    });
});

// generator test 2
// adding more automation

function runGen(gen) {
    return function (done) {
        var iter = gen(function (value) {
            var r = iter.next(value);
            if (r.done)
                done();
        });
        iter.next();
    }
}

describe('yield demo 2', function () {
    it('works', runGen(function *(advance) {
        var result = yield asyncFunc('quux', advance);
        expect(result).toBe('quux-ok');
    }));
});
```

Comment: I am understand all except last sentence. If I understand it right I need remove `cb` from arguments and change `cb(res)` => `done(res)` into my async function. And write something like your `run()` function.

Comment: @StepanLoginov: I added an example on how to use this in testing.

Comment: thx a lot. I despaired with this topic today (`mocha` finished the test before callback code started). So I did synchronizing with your first example and "flag + sleep" technique. Now i can throw out all my `sleep`s and do it well.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
function* request (url, query) {
    supertest(app.listen())
        .get(url)
        .query(query)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            yield res;
        });
}

it('Check something after response', done => {
    const res = request(this.url, this.query).next();
    expect(res).to.be.defined
});
```

Comment: I am not sure what is "to.be.defined" part means. But I don't need check response fact. I need check that server create appropriate entities in database while processing request etc... But your code looks really pretty.

Comment: Oh sorry for the "to.be.defined" part, it was just a "chai" way of expressing what you want to test. You can just use next() for your function to yield the request and then proceed to check whatever you want server side